# Send and receive private message

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, identity, .net-framework-version

I started writing a website where I used NET Framework 4.8, Webforms, and ASP.NET Identity.

How do I allow users to communicate with each other via private messaging (without any protocol like smtp and in local)?

Each of the users should have features such as inbox, create new message, delete message, draft, etc.

Comment: A connection between two users always uses a Protocol.  The protocol can be TCP, UDP, HTTP, FTP, and SMTP (Simple Mail Transport Protocol).

Comment: Is there a specific reason for using an ancient framework?

Comment: Which of the protocols are more suitable for transferring files and messages locally? @jdweng

Comment: FTP is used for file transfers and UDP/TCP for messages.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you don't need anything more then say a web form, and some controls like a subject text box, to who, and then a text area to enter the message.

Think of many "board" or "forum" types of software. Even this forum (stack overflow) has a menu up right that shows when you have a message. There no special  "protocol" when say comments are added to a message.

so, you could create a table with messages in it. Things like "user" and the message text could be stored in that table.

So, not even any kind of "real" emails need to be sent to anyone. Thus when users logon to the site, you could have a little box or label in the upper right corner that shows "New messages".

So an good example would be this forum.

I also spend time say on UtterAccess (a forum for ms-access developers).

When I go to that forum right now? I see this:

[image]

So for pending notices, or even messages from others on that system? There is no real actually emails being sent, but only a "message" being added to a table, and when I go to the side, a simple SQL pulls all my un-read or "pending" messages from that database, counts any un-read, and puts a number for me to see.

when I click on that "messages", or "notices", then a simple web form to display that message is displayed.

And if I delete the message, then you can have a row in the table, change the stated to "deleted". Now, you can add a "UI" to the end user that shows a "in box", delete box, and even sent items box.

However, ALL of those messages can be placed in ONE table, and you have a column that defines the message type.

So, these so called "posting boards" and message systems? They are rather easy to build, and they are VERY common for many sites I use and visit.

In fact, in some cases, they don't even EVER send a REAL email to the user(s) in question. (so you are encouraged to logon to that given site, and see/check and view any messages that others from that web site have left for you).

In many ways, this is not un-like a message board like in university days, in which on campus living areas often had and have a message board down at the end of the hallway. thus announcements, and things like one selling their furniture etc.? Well, the term bulletin board was used and that term carried over to web sites.

I am betting in one after noon, you could EASY build and have such a board working.

I mean, here is a mock up - took me all of 3 minutes with drag + drop.

I dragged in a treeview, but I not sure if I even need one.

[image]

code to fill out the grid of messages is

```
    Dim rstMsg = MyRst("SELECT Sent, Mtype, [User], Body FROM Emails", My.Settings.Email)
    GridView1.DataSource = rstMsg
    GridView1.DataBind()
```

So, message boards, and you "building" up a message system?

Not really hard, and in fact is a great idea and great test project to make.

So, near EVERY system I log into these days, including that of this board (stack overflow) often will and has some kind of message system.

That message system notifies when you go back to the site and logon. Really, all such systems are just a few simple and easy database tables in which messages are simple add, or delete operations.

As I pointed out, even StackOverflow warns and notes when you have comments on a post etc.

Opps, I just noticed my text for "cancel" was wrong, should have been this:

[image]

Anyway, you get the idea, and such system are very easy to make.